# How to manually set a boolean array in just one code line (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

How do you manually assign a boolean value to every array positions in just one code line?

Look the code fragment below. I don't wanna manually put `a[0]=true;` `a[1]=true;` `a[2]=false;` ...

```
public class stackArray {

   static boolean [] a = new boolean [6];

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      a[0]=true;
      a[1]=true;
      a[2]=false;

      for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
         System.out.println(a[i]);
      }

   }
}
```

I'm really looking something similar to

```
a= {true, true, false, false, false, false};
```

but unfortunately it doesn't works :(

Can anybody help me? I googled it but I couldn't find this particular case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `static boolean [] a = new boolean [6]{true, true, false, false, false, false};` should work. Check top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java).

Comment: @AntonH That will not compile.  You probably meant `static boolean[] a = { true, true, false, false, false, false };`.

Comment: @VGR You're right that it won't compile, but just removing the `6` is enough to make it compile. I didn't test before posting, which is my mistake. Maybe not necessary, but close to OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

use the [fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-boolean:A-boolean-) method in the Arrays helper class

```
boolean[] a = new boolean[6];
Arrays.fill(a, true);
```

Comment: OP doesn't want all `true` values, though.

Comment: ummm.... what do you mean? OP wrote ***to every array positions....***

Comment: I mean that in the example array he provided, the different elements of the array don't all have the same value. Some are `true`, some are `false`. Your answer sets all elements to `true`.

Comment: @AntonH is right. Anyways, thank you guys for your help! I found the solution in other answer

Answer (score 0):

If the array reference is not shared in some other variable then you can just reassign to a new array:

```
a = new boolean[] {true, .. };
```

Otherwise if you really want it in one line while keeping the array the same you can do

```
System.arrayCopy(new boolean[] { true, ... }, 0, a, 0, a.length };
```

but it doesn't look like better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
boolean [] a = new boolean []{false, false, true};
```

Comment: Thank you Julio, that was exactly what I was looking for, is simple but I couldn't get it!

Comment: You don’t need the `new boolean[]` at all.